# MySQL returns one row

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, row

i have this php code

```
if ($settings['ht_showlastwinners'] == 'yes') {
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ht_history ');


    if ($row = $db->fetch_array( $query )) {
        $row['username'] = $db->fetchOne('SELECT username FROM members WHERE id=' . $row['user_id'] );
        $htwinners[] = $row;
    }

    $smarty->assign( 'htwinners', $htwinners );
}
```

when on a .tpl file i use

```
  {section name=w loop=$htwinners}
            <tr>
                <td>{$htwinners[w].username}</td>
                <td>{$htwinners[w].bet}</td>
                <td>${$htwinners[w].win}</td>
            </tr>
            {/section}
```

it only gives me one row. So i tried to print value of htwinners in php page and it gives me effectively only one row, so i suppose the problem is the code, when it "copies" data from $ht_history in the new $htwinners associating/replacing user id with username, fetches only one row.

Thanks in advance for answers, i'm a pratical (not a lot) on php, i tried to look for similar code-problems, but didn't find anything and this code i have looks like me without error to my restricted knowledge, but obviously i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change "if" to "while"
2. You also need to change "$db" to "$query"
3. Check the parameter type for fetch_array.  It expects a result type constant which is an integer

`while ($row = $query->fetch_array( MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {`

Comment: I fell like i dumb, i tried everything, except this. Really Thanks!

Comment: No probs.  I also added a note about the parameter for fetch_array

Comment: i did only the first point and it works well, no needing 2 and 3. Could you explain the other 2?

Comment: 2. fetch_array is a method of the mysqli_result object which is returned by the "query()" function.  I'm not sure why calling fetch_array on the $db variable works in your case.  It would depend on the code that precedes the sample you gave.  I assume you are using mysqli.  3. Take a look at the documentation for fetch_array and you will see that it expects an integer parameter (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).  Passing it a mysqli_result as you are doing is not valid and it probably works because it is implicitly casting it to zero.